# Difference between nil and null in YAML

Tags: null, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm working on a Liquid template in Jekyll, and I have 2 places where I'm not sure what to use: `nil`, `null`, or just empty.

1. In the [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/):

   ```
   ---
   layout: nil|null|<empty>
   ---
   ```

   - When I use `nil`, I get `Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in sitemap.xml does not exist, as [this thread demonstrates](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2730).
   - `null` and blank both have no error.
2. In Liquid templating:

   ```
   {% if post.date != nil %}
   ```

   - `null`, `nil`, and blank all work, but `""` makes the statement true, when the variable is not set.

So which should I use? Why? (Does this have anything to do with Ruby? I didn't add the tag.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the front matter, use `null` (as you've already seen). The front matter is interpreted as YAML which defines a null value as `null` ([and possibly also with a tilde `~`](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html) though I've never tried that).

In the liquid templates, for the most part you'd be better off with leaving the comparison out:

```
{% if post.date %}
```

As that typically achieves what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In YAML, the term "nil" is used to represent an explicit absence of a value where as "null" is used to represent an unknown or undefined value.

Comment: What's the difference in practice?

Comment: The "null" is more commonly used in YAML, it signifies that the value of the key is explicitly undefined or missing. On the other hand, the usage of "nil" may be specific to certain libraries or frameworks that use YAML. Some programming languages or YAML parsers might treat "nil" as a special value to represent an explicit absence of a value. However, it's important to note that this usage of "nil" is not universally recognized or understood by all YAML implementations.